# Converting to NotificationCompat breaks SetSmallIcon functionality?

Tags: xamarin, notifications

I've been having some trouble moving Notification to the Compat library version: In the main library, I used to just convert an icon to a bitmap (api 23 and up) and do SetSmallIcon(icon) to show a dynamic notification icon.

But the Compat version has only an int argument (I assume it is the resource ID), and I cannot find any information as to how to generate/convert/add my bitmap and/or icon in it.

*The bitmap Is basically generated text converted into a bitmap via a canvas which show the most vital information.*

My question is: Is there a way to make a class variable into a resource, or get its ID that works like a resoource ID, or some other hack that will allow me to actually add my bitmap that I create at runtime?

Comment: you could try to use `RemoteViews` to custom your notification

Comment: Does that even work for the notification icon on the top?

Comment: yes,you only should add your custom layout to RemoteView

Comment: but there's a limitation of RemoteViews , they just don't support custom widgets:

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. Refer the line where `icon` is being used

```
var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                 .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.NotifIconSis).SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(33, 150, 243))
                 .SetContentTitle(user.Organization)
                 .SetSubText(user.ModuleName).SetStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().BigText(user.BodyText))
                 .SetContentText(user.BodyText)
                 .SetAutoCancel(true)
                 .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                 .Build();
var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
//var notification = RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification);
//var mp = MediaPlayer.Create(ApplicationContext, notification);
//mp.Start();
//notificationManager.Notify(redomId, notificationBuilder);
```

Comment: That is not what I am looking for- I have a variable bitmap which I need to set as a small icon. Not a resource that I need to be setting